# Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag exception - Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-context

I have created a camera activity which will take pic from rear and front camera. But I am keep getting above mentioned error can any one help me out :

Seems like i am doing some mistake in Menifest file in calling intent but not able to figure it out what mistake i am doing.

Here is my **CameraActivity.java**

```
    public class CameraActivity extends Activity {

        private static CameraActivity inst;

        private Camera mCamera;
        private CameraPreview mPreview;
        private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;
        private FrameLayout preview;
        private boolean isRecording = false;

        private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
        private static final int CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
        public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
        public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;
        private static boolean isPictureTaken = false;
        private static int cameraCount = 0;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

            Log.d("TestCase", "in camera activity on create");

            inst = this;

            Intent localIntent = getIntent();
            //Intent localIntent = new Intent("com.test.TestCase.core.util.CameraActivity");
            //localIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
            String cameraMode = localIntent.getExtras().getString("Camera");
            Log.d("TestCase", "CameraMode" + cameraMode);
            if (cameraMode.equals("FrontCamera"))
                inst.mCamera = openFrontFacingCamera();
            else
                inst.mCamera = openRearFacingCamera();

            setCameraView();

        }

        private void setCameraView() {

            if (inst.mCamera != null) {
                Log.d("TestCase", "Got the Camera Instance");
            } else {
                Log.d("TestCase", "Camera Instance obtained is null");
            }

            // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
            inst.mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
            inst.preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
            inst.preview.addView(mPreview);

        }

        private Camera openRearFacingCamera() {
            Camera cam = null;
            Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
            cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
            Log.d("Camera", "Camera COunt : " + cameraCount);

            for (int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++) {

                Log.d("Camera", " CamIdx : " + camIdx);

                Camera.getCameraInfo(camIdx, cameraInfo);

                if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
                    try {
                        cam = Camera.open(camIdx);
                        break;
                    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                        for (StackTraceElement st : e.getStackTrace())
                            Log.d("Camera", st.toString());
                        // Log.e("Camera failed to open: " +
                        // e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    }
                }
            }

            return cam;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    // Image captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to:\n" + data.getData(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                    // User cancelled the image capture
                } else {
                    // Image capture failed, advise user
                }
            }

            if (requestCode == CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    // Video captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Video saved to:\n" + data.getData(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                    // User cancelled the video capture
                } else {
                    // Video capture failed, advise user
                }
            }
        }

        /** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
        private Camera openFrontFacingCamera() {
            // int cameraCount = 0;
            Camera cam = null;
            Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
            cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
            Log.d("Camera", "Camera COunt : " + cameraCount);

            for (int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++) {

                Log.d("Camera", " CamIdx : " + camIdx);

                Camera.getCameraInfo(camIdx, cameraInfo);

                if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                    try {
                        cam = Camera.open(camIdx);
                        break;
                    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                        for (StackTraceElement st : e.getStackTrace())
                            Log.d("Camera", st.toString());
                        // Log.e("Camera failed to open: " +
                        // e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    }
                }
            }

            return cam;
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            try {
                super.onStart();

            } catch (Exception localException) {
                Log.d("TestCase", localException.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.camera, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

                File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
                if (pictureFile == null) {
                    Log.d("TestCase",
                            "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: ");
                    return;
                }

                try {
                    Log.d("TestCase", "Picture taken");
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                    fos.write(data);
                    fos.close();

                    Log.d("TestCase", "Picture saved");
                    CameraActivity.isPictureTaken = true;

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    Log.d("TestCase", "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d("TestCase", "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
                }

                try {
                    inst.mCamera.stopPreview();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
                }

                // inst.mCamera.release();

                // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
                // reformatting changes here

                // start preview with new settings
                try {
                    inst.mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder());
                    inst.mCamera.startPreview();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("TestCase",
                            "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        };

        public void onCameraClick(View view) {
            try {

                takePicture();

            } catch (Exception localException) {
                Log.d("TestCase", localException.getMessage());
            }
        }

        private void takePicture() {

            inst.mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
        }

        /** Create a File for saving an image or video */
        private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {
            // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
            // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

            File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                    Environment
                            .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                    "TestCase_CamMedia");
            // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
            // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

            // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
            if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
                if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                    Log.d("TestCase", "failed to create directory");
                    return null;
                }
            }

            // Create a media file name
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                    Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
            File mediaFile;
            if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
                mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                        + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
            } else if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
                mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                        + "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");
            } else {
                return null;
            }

            return mediaFile;
        }

        private boolean prepareVideoRecorder() {

            // mCamera = getCameraInstance();
            inst.mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            // Step 1: Unlock and set camera to MediaRecorder
            inst.mCamera.unlock();

            inst.mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

            // Step 2: Set sources
            inst.mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
            inst.mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

            // Step 3: Set a CamcorderProfile (requires API Level 8 or higher)
            inst.mMediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile
                    .get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));

            // Step 4: Set output file
            inst.mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
                    .toString());

            // Step 5: Set the preview output
            inst.mMediaRecorder
                    .setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder().getSurface());

            // Step 6: Prepare configured MediaRecorder
            try {

                mMediaRecorder.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Log.d("TestCase",
                        "IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: "
                                + e.getMessage());
                inst.releaseMediaRecorder();
                return false;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("TestCase",
                        "IOException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
                inst.releaseMediaRecorder();
                return false;
            }
            return true;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            inst.releaseMediaRecorder(); // if you are using MediaRecorder, release
                                            // it first
            inst.releaseCamera(); // release the camera immediately on pause event
        }

        private void releaseMediaRecorder() {
            if (inst.mMediaRecorder != null) {
                inst.mMediaRecorder.reset(); // clear recorder configuration
                inst.mMediaRecorder.release(); // release the recorder object
                inst.mMediaRecorder = null;
                inst.mCamera.lock(); // lock camera for later use
            }
        }

        private void releaseCamera() {
            if (inst.mCamera != null) {
                inst.mCamera.release(); // release the camera for other applications
                inst.mCamera = null;
            }
        }

        public void recordVideo() {
            if (!inst.isRecording) {
                if (inst.prepareVideoRecorder()) {
                    // Camera is available and unlocked, MediaRecorder is prepared,
                    // now you can start recording
                    inst.mMediaRecorder.start();
                    Log.d("TestCase", "started video recording");
                    // inform the user that recording has started

                    inst.isRecording = true;
                } else
                    inst.releaseMediaRecorder();
            }
        }

        public void stopRecording() {
            if (inst.isRecording) {
                // stop recording and release camera
                inst.mMediaRecorder.stop(); // stop the recording
                Log.d("TestCase", "stopped video recording");
                inst.releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object
                inst.mCamera.lock(); // take camera access back from MediaRecorder

                // inform the user that recording has stopped
                inst.isRecording = false;
            }
        }

        public void onRecordVideo(View view) {
            try {
                inst.recordVideo();
            } catch (Exception localException) {
                Log.d("TestCase", localException.getMessage());
            }
        }

        public void onStopRecording(View view) {
            try {
                inst.stopRecording();
            } catch (Exception localException) {
                Log.d("TestCase", localException.getMessage());
            }
        }

        public static boolean TakePicture() {
            inst.takePicture();
            return CameraActivity.isPictureTaken;
        }

        public static boolean RecordVideo() {
            inst.recordVideo();
            return inst.isRecording;
        }

        public static boolean StopVideo() {
            inst.stopRecording();
            return !inst.isRecording;
        }

        public static void CloseCamera() {
            inst.finish();
        }

        public static boolean ToggleCamera() throws Exception {

            for(int i=1; i<=3 ; i++) {
                if(i%2==0)
                    inst.mCamera = inst.openRearFacingCamera();
                else
                    inst.mCamera = inst.openFrontFacingCamera();

                if (inst.mCamera != null) {
                    Log.d("TestCase", "Got the Camera Instance");
                } else {
                    Log.d("TestCase", "Camera Instance obtained is null");
                }
                inst.setCameraView();
                Thread.sleep(10000L);
            }
            return true;

        }
    }



**Here is ManifestFile :**

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.TestCase.TestCase"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:maxSdkVersion="21"
            android:minSdkVersion="14"
            android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" /
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name=".main_activities.TestCaseActivity"
                android:label="@style/AppTheme" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name="com.TestCase.TestCase.core.util.CameraActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_camera" >
            </activity>

            <activity android:name=".main_activities.SetPreferenceActivity" />
            <activity
                android:name=".main_activities.SummaryActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_summary" >
            </activity>

            <activity
                android:name="com.TestCase.TestCase.main_activities.AboutActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_about" >
            </activity>

            <service android:name=".services.MasterService" />
            <service android:name=".services.TestCaseBootService" />
            <service android:name=".services.ActivityLauncherService" />

            <receiver android:name=".recievers.BootReciever" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
            <receiver android:name="com.TestCase.TestCase.framework.TestActionEndBroadcastReceiver" >
            </receiver>
            <receiver android:name="com.TestCase.TestCase.system.TestProgressUpdater$UpdateBroadcast" >
            </receiver>
        </application>

    </manifest>

Logcat : 

 11-03 19:31:21.782: D/TestCase(11635): [11.03.14_19:31:021]    came back from thread starting itest action 
    11-03 19:31:21.782: D/TestCase(11635): [11.03.14_19:31:021] Came back after starting action thread
    11-03 19:31:21.804: D/TestCase(11635): [11.03.14_19:31:021] from thread starting itest action 
    11-03 19:31:21.806: D/TestCase(11635): [11.03.14_19:31:021] Recieved onFinishPrepare
    11-03 19:31:21.834: D/TestCase(11635): [11.03.14_19:31:021] Error found when test is running: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
    11-03 19:31:21.834: D/TestCase(11635):  at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1232)
    11-03 19:31:21.834: D/TestCase(11635):  at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1219)
    11-03 19:31:21.834: D/TestCase(11635):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:322)
    11-03 19:31:21.834: D/TestCase(11635):  at com.originatorTestCase.TestCase.core.multimedia.LaunchRearCameraTestAction.start(LaunchRearCameraTestAction.java:24)
    11-03 19:31:21.834: D/TestCase(11635):  at com.originatorTestCase.TestCase.framework.TestActionExecutor.startAction(TestActionExecutor.java:54)
    11-03 19:31:21.834: D/TestCase(11635):  at com.originatorTestCase.TestCase.framework.TestActionExecutor.access$1(TestActionExecutor.java:49)
    11-03 19:31:21.834: D/TestCase(11635):  at com.originatorTestCase.TestCase.framework.TestActionExecutor$ActionThread.run(TestActionExecutor.java:166)
    11-03 19:31:21.837: D/TestCase(11635): [11.03.14_19:31:021] TestAction Execution Finished : LaunchRearCamera id : 3
    11-03 19:31:21.838: D/TestCase(11635): [11.03.14_19:31:021] TestRunner onFinish(ITestAction) : [null]nullnull(null):
    11-03 19:31:21.862: D/TestCase(11635): [11.03.14_19:31:021] Completed [LaunchRearCamera TestAction] iteration : 1
    11-03 19:31:21.862: D/TestCase(11635): RESULT = [action="LaunchRearCamera" status="FAIL" iteration="1" startTime="11.03.14 19:31:21" duration="0" endTime="11.03.14 19:31:21" failedReason=" [null]nullnull(null): Executing error : android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want? ""]
    11-03 19:31:21.863: D/TestCase(11635): [11.03.14_19:31:021] Has errors so stop test case RearCameraTakePictureTest
    11-03 19:31:21.886: D/TestCase(11635): [11.03.14_19:31:021] Completed total 1 iterations for action LaunchRearCamera.
    11-03 19:31:21.888: D/TestCase(11635): [11.03.14_19:31:021] ==========================================================
    11-03 19:31:21.906: D/TestCase(11635): [11.03.14_19:31:021] ==========================================================
    11-03 19:31:21.912: D/TestCase(11635): [11.03.14_19:31:021] Start Test Action TakePicture
    11-03 19:31:21.922: D/TestCase(11635): [11.03.14_19:31:021] Preparing for test action TakePicture
    11-03 19:31:21.925: D/TestCase(11635): [11.03.14_19:31:021] Begin [TakePicture TestAction] iteration : 1
    11-03 19:31:21.928: D/TestCase(11635): [11.03.14_19:31:021] Next random TakePicture-duration = 15
    11-03 19:31:21.947: D/TestCase(11635): [11.03.14_19:31:021] triggering schedule Task
    11-03 19:31:21.966: D/TestCase(11635): [11.03.14_19:31:021] initializing task infor
    11-03 19:31:21.968: D/TestCase(11635): [11.03.14_19:31:021] initializing thread
    11-03 19:31:21.974: D/TestCase(11635): [11.03.14_19:31:021] adding thread to task info
    11-03 19:31:21.976: D/TestCase(11635): [11.03.14_19:31:021] putting thread refrence in concurrent hash map
    11-03 19:31:21.977: D/TestCase(11635): [11.03.14_19:31:021] starting thread
    11-03 19:31:21.979: D/TestCase(11635): [11.03.14_19:31:021] came back after starting thread
    11-03 19:31:21.991: D/TestCase(11635): [11.03.14_19:31:021] in Action thread. 
    11-03 19:31:21.991: D/TestCase(11635): [11.03.14_19:31:021] Acquire WL for TakePicture
    11-03 19:31:21.995: D/TestCase(11635): [11.03.14_19:31:021] came back after triggering schedule Task
    11-03 19:31:21.996: D/TestCase(11635): [11.03.14_19:31:021] Came back after call back of testAction : LaunchRearCamera
    11-03 19:31:21.996: D/TestCase(11635): [11.03.14_19:31:021] Came back after starting action thread
    11-03 19:31:22.014: D/TestCase(11635): [11.03.14_19:31:022] from thread starting itest action 
    11-03 19:31:22.015: D/TestCase(11635): [11.03.14_19:31:022] Recieved onFinishPrepare
    11-03 19:31:22.024: D/TestCase(11635): [11.03.14_19:31:022] Error found when test is running: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke direct method 'void com..core.util.CameraActivity.takePicture()' on a null object reference
    11-03 19:31:22.024: D/TestCase(11635):  at core.util.CameraActivity.TakePicture(CameraActivity.java:403)
    11-03 19:31:22.024: D/TestCase(11635):  at
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your problem is here:

`at com.qualcomm.post.core.multimedia.LaunchRearCameraTestAction.start(LaunchRearCameraTestAction.java:24)`

In this code you need to add the new task flag to the `Intent` before calling `startActivity()` with:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Comment: @ David Wasser !!! Thankuuu So much Devid .. u saved my job :) Thanks a lot again...

Answer (score 0):

I think i had this problem is the past.

Try uncommenting this line:

```
//localIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Comment: I have tried it but still i am getting the same issue. I am adding logcate log also.

Comment: Right idea, wrong location - this needs to be in the (apparently test?) code which sends the intent from a non-activity context (perhaps a service).  Setting this on the Activity in the manifest might be a workaround, but it's unclear if it's desired to have that in general.

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for quick reply . I am really struggling to fix this issue. if possible can you please suggest the code which can help me.